# How to use a biber on texwork 2017

Tags: biber

I have installed the texwork 2017 and I am trying to use biber on it. I am trying to create a bib file to use it as a bibliography database but error keeps appearing us like the screenshot below.[image]

What is wrong? What does it mean by "did you pass the beckend-biber option to Biblatex"? Could anyone please help me how to solve this error?

Comment: Did you ever compile a simple hello world latex file?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/biblatex-in-a-nutshell-for-beginners

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations

Comment: This is I think a duplicate of the 'basic advice' question, but perhaps you want the 'editor set up' one?

Comment: One important thing to realise is that you do not compile your `.bib` file with Biber. You need to run Biber on your actual document. Assuming you have a `.tex` document called `myfirst.tex` you need to run `pdflatex myfirst`, `biber myfirst` and `pdflatex myfirst` (regardless of the name of your `.bib` file).

Comment: Also relevant https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864